# Amazon Scrape Product Detail Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
URL = "https://www.amazon.com/TRESemm%C3%A9-Botanique-Shampoo-Nourish-Replenish/dp/B0199WNJE8/ref=sxin_14_pa_sp_search_thematic_sspa?content-id=amzn1.sym.a15c61b7-4b93-404d-bb70-88600dfb718d%3Aamzn1.sym.a15c61b7-4b93-404d-bb70-88600dfb718d&crid=2HG5WSUDCJBMZ&cv_ct_cx=hair%2Btresemme&keywords=hair%2Btresemme&pd_rd_i=B0199WNJE8&pd_rd_r=28d72361-7f35-4b1a-be43-98e7103da70c&pd_rd_w=6UL4P&pd_rd_wg=JtUqB&pf_rd_p=a15c61b7-4b93-404d-bb70-88600dfb718d&pf_rd_r=DFPZNAG391M5JS55R6HP&qid=1660432925&sprefix=hair%2Btresemme%2Caps%2C116&sr=1-3-a73d1c8c-2fd2-4f19-aa41-2df022bcb241-spons&smid=A3DEFW12560V8M&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExQlM3VFpGRVM5Tk8wJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjE5MjQwM01JV0FNN1pOMlRHSSZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNTA1MDQyMlQ5RjhRQUxIWEdaUiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX3NlYXJjaF90aGVtYXRpYyZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU&th=1"
webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "lxml")

# Outer Tag Object
title = soup.find("span", attrs={"class":'a-list-item'}).text.strip()
print(title)
```

This is my code:

I am trying to scrape the product detail page information best seller rank and sub-category best seller rank if you scroll down the page you will see it. But I am only getting the category Beauty Personal Care. I need the rank. Please help.

Comment: You probably need Selenium for this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your element more specific for example with [`css selectors`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) with focus of bestseller link:

```
soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div a[href*="bestsellers"]').previous.strip().split()[0]
```

Alternative could be selecting the `span` that contains *Best Seller* in the section with `id` *detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div* :

```
soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[2].strip().split()[0]
```

*Be aware that you always should check if the element is available.*

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}

URL = "https://www.amazon.com/TRESemm%C3%A9-Botanique-Shampoo-Nourish-Replenish/dp/B0199WNJE8/ref=sxin_14_pa_sp_search_thematic_sspa?content-id=amzn1.sym.a15c61b7-4b93-404d-bb70-88600dfb718d%3Aamzn1.sym.a15c61b7-4b93-404d-bb70-88600dfb718d&crid=2HG5WSUDCJBMZ&cv_ct_cx=hair%2Btresemme&keywords=hair%2Btresemme&pd_rd_i=B0199WNJE8&pd_rd_r=28d72361-7f35-4b1a-be43-98e7103da70c&pd_rd_w=6UL4P&pd_rd_wg=JtUqB&pf_rd_p=a15c61b7-4b93-404d-bb70-88600dfb718d&pf_rd_r=DFPZNAG391M5JS55R6HP&qid=1660432925&sprefix=hair%2Btresemme%2Caps%2C116&sr=1-3-a73d1c8c-2fd2-4f19-aa41-2df022bcb241-spons&smid=A3DEFW12560V8M&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExQlM3VFpGRVM5Tk8wJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjE5MjQwM01JV0FNN1pOMlRHSSZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNTA1MDQyMlQ5RjhRQUxIWEdaUiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX3NlYXJjaF90aGVtYXRpYyZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU&th=1"
webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content)
soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[2].strip().split()[0]
```

##### Output

```
#224,708
```

Comment: Omg it worked! Thank you so much there's another rank #5774 in hair shampoo under bestseller rank. There's no text. How can I scrape that? I will mark your answer as best answer.

Comment: Happy to help - While your original question could be improved, your additional one would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus and you could do some practice - [ask]

Comment: Thank you so much I marked your answer as the selected answer. I figured it out using: Subrank = soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[5].get_text().split()[0]. But I still have a question: how to appropriately write in this format? What's your logic behind it why did you grab '#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span: and did you add # and span because I only see detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div in the HTML. Sorry I am a beginner. Thanks so much in advanced.

Comment: added a link to my answer that should cover your question regarding [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks like you are an expert. If you have time, could you take a look at my loop question that I posted. I am new to Python and I am still trying to learn. Really appreciate it again!